# How to use one table multiple times for inner join in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to make a table that includes join between 3 tables in the MSSS 2008. There is a fact table, a date table, and a course table. I should join them to make a base table. In date table there is a one parameter that name is Academic Year lookup, and the values in this parameter is like 2000/1, 2001/2. This parameter in the base table should separate to three parameter such as CensusYear, StartYear, and ApplicationYear. Therefore, I need the data table multiple times. I executed a inner join query, and already I have four inner join statement, but I am getting some extra years, and I'm losing some years. I believe, my query should be wrong somewhere.

The attached file is include the design view that created in the MS Access, it'll help to see the tables, and understand what I need to create.
[Design View in Ms Access][1]

```
SELECT 
A.[EventCount], 
B.[AcademicYearLookup] AS [CensusYear], 
C.[AcademicYearLookup] AS [StartYear], 
D.[AcademicYearLookup] AS [ApplicationYear],
B.[CurrentWeekComparisonFlag], 
B.[AcademicWeekOfYear],

case 
      when A.[ApplicationCensusSK] = 1 then 'Same Year'

      when A.[ApplicationCensusSK] = 2 then 'Next Year'

      when A.[ApplicationCensusSK] = 5 then 'Last Year'
      ELSE 'Other'
END as [CensusYearDescription],

B.[CurrentAcademicYear],
A.[StudentCodeBK], 
A.[ApplicationSequenceNoBK], 
A.[CourseSK], 
A.[CourseGroupSK], 
A.[CourseMoaSK], 
A.[CboSK], 
A.[CourseTaughtAbroadSK], 
A.[ApplicationStatusSK],
A.[ApplicationFeeStatusSK], 
A.[DecisionResponseSK], 
A.[NationalityCountrySK], 
A.[DomicileCountrySK], 
A.[TargetRegionSK], 
A.[InternationalSponsorSK] INTO dbo.[BaseTable3yrs]

FROM Student.FactApplicationSnapshot A 

INNER JOIN Conformed.DimDate AS B ON A.[CensusDateSK] = B.[DateSK] 

INNER JOIN Conformed.DimDate AS C ON A.[AcademicYearStartDateSK] = C.[DateSK] 

INNER JOIN Conformed.DimDate AS D ON A.[ApplicationDateSK] = D.[DateSK]

INNER JOIN Student.DimCourse ON A.CourseSK = Student.DimCourse.CourseSK

WHERE (((B.CurrentAcademicYear) In (0,-1)) 
AND ((A.ApplicationCensusSK) In (1,2,5)) 
AND ((Student.DimCourse.DepartmentShortName)= 'TEACH ED'));

/* the query to check that the result it's correct or not, and I check it by academic week of year, and I found that I am lossing some data, and I have some extra data, means maybe join is wrong*/

select * from [BaseTable3yrs]
where [StudentCodeBK]= '26002423' 
AND [ApplicationSequenceNoBK] = '0101'
order by [AcademicWeekOfYear]
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing recursive joins like this, it's easy to get duplicate records. You could try gathering the Conformed data separately into a [table variable](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) and then joining to it.  This would also make your query more readable.

You might also try a SELECT DISTINCT on your main query.